# Dynamically resizing a Label within a Scrollview?

Tags: kivy

Let's say you have a setup like the following:

```
ScrollView:
   size_hint: (1, 0.5)

   Label:
      size_hint: (1, None)
```

Initially, the Label has no content/text. If I understand correctly, when the objects are created, the Label's height is `None`.

When the app is run, the Label's `text` property is set to multiple lines of text, which should push the content of the Label outside the boundaries of the ScrollView. However, for scrolling to happen, it seems that the Label's y dimension/height has to be dynamically resized.

What is the best way to dynamically resize the height of the Label in accordance with the Label's new content such that a scrolling action can occur?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual text is displayed in a Rectangle whose size is *not* coupled to the Label size by default. When the amount of text is large, this grows larger and can exceed the Label bounds, but does not resize the label.

The relevant property controlling the real size of the displayed text is `Label.text_size`. To get the behaviour you want, you can simply do:

```
ScrollView:
   size_hint: (1, 0.5)

   Label:
      size_hint: (1, None)
      height: self.text_size[1]
```

This binds the height of the label to track the height of the displayed text, and so should give you the behaviour you want.

As a side note, it's often useful to change or watch `text_size`. For instance, to make the text wrap at the edges of the Label rather than relying on manual newlines, you can set `text_size: self.size` which means the text will be automatically wrapped if its width would exceed the label width. This is also important if working with halign or valign, which control the text position within its texture and *not* within the label itself - those properties will have no visible effect unless you manually set text_size to (again) something larger than the space the text actually takes up.

Edit: As per your comments below, here's an example of a Label in one of my apps, which grows vertically if the length of text increases (so the user can scroll), but also automatically wraps text when its width is greater than the label width. It seems I actually did this by putting the Label in a GridLayout, which I vaguely remember was important for some reason.

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    spacing: 10
    size_hint_y: None
    height: thetb.texture_size[1]

    Label:
        id: thetb
        text: 'whatever'
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: (1, None)
        size: self.parent.width, self.texture_size[1]
```

You can see I use text_size to control the text boundingbox (so it wraps at the label edges), but bind the GridLayout height to really track the texture_size height. The GridLayout is placed in the ScrollView, and I get exactly the behaviour I think you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and thorough explanation, inclement! It looks like your suggestion is the right idea, but when I try to implement it, I get the error message: 'ValueError: None is not allowed for LabelCustom.height'. I'm using a custom label class, but the same occurs with a generic Label. Any suggestions?

Comment: Found this variant: 'height: self.texture_size[1]'. 'self.text_size[1]' seems to be comparable to LabelBase's 'content_height' property. It solves the text size/scrolling problem, but as you've pointed out, there is still the issue of the text not wrapping properly. The 'text_size: self.size' solution produces a warning along the lines of "Clock - too much iteration before the next frame' - I'm guessing that this may have something to do with the length of the text... Will tinker with it some more.

Comment: I just checked out how I achieved this in my own apps, and there was a bit more subtlety than I remembered...I'm not sure if it's totally necessary, but it does work! I added the example code in an edit above.

Comment: Yep, that takes care of the text cropping issue. Thanks again!

Comment: I think the purpose of the GridLayout was just an easy way of specifying a margin. I've got it working in a BoxLayout with no issues.