# Position and wrap text on Kivy floats on slides in a carousel without it spilling into adjacent slides

Tags: python, kivy

I have a Kivy carousel that is supposed to look like a baby book. Each slide has a float on it and each float has a picture, a label and some text. There are several problems, the text spills onto neighbouring slides, I can't get it to wrap and/or resize itself to stay in its float on its slide.

I have read lots of documentation and tried lots of things with pos_hint and size_hint, and text_size and size, but nothing is working as I expect. See for example [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html) and [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342472/dynamically-resizing-a-kivy-label-and-button-on-the-python-side) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50416284/kivy-sizing-buttons-to-fit-wrapped-text-within-dropdown).

[image: Wide view showing all text]

[image: Narrow view showing no wrapping, no resizing, and text spilling]

The code is below. It is long but most of it is just adding widgets to parent widgets.

```
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout 
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage 
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel 

def render_kivy_carousel(): 
    # Set the windows background colour.
    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 0, 1)
    # Create the book renditions root widget.
    bkr = Carousel() 
    bkr.width = 100
    bkr.loop = True
    # Add the page widgets.

    """PAGE 1
    """
    # Create the pages base widget
    flo = FloatLayout()

    # Build the image
    image = AsyncImage(source='https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/195082.jpg',
                allow_stretch = True,
                keep_ratio = True,
                size_hint = (0.5, 0.5),
                pos_hint = {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.25},)
    flo.add_widget(image)

    # Build the label
    label = Label(text='Bee',
                color=(0,0,0,1),
                font_size=60,
                size_hint=(0.25, 0.25),
                pos_hint={'bottom': 1, 'left': 1},)
    flo.add_widget(label)
    
    # Build the text
    text = Label(text='The bee buzzes looking for flowers',
                color=(0,0,0,1),
                font_size=20,
                size_hint=(0.25, 0.25),
                pos_hint={'top': 1, 'right': 1},)
    flo.add_widget(text)
    bkr.add_widget(flo)

    """PAGE 2
    """
    # Create the pages base widget
    flo = FloatLayout()

    # Build the image
    image = AsyncImage(source='https://i.pinimg.com/originals/60/5b/c0/605bc0c0ef2645b43d64300bb2d82ed1.jpg',
                allow_stretch = True,
                keep_ratio = True,
                size_hint = (0.5, 0.5),
                pos_hint = {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.25},)
    flo.add_widget(image)

    # Build the label
    label = Label(text='Beetle',
                color=(0,0,0,1),
                font_size=60,
                size_hint=(0.25, 0.25),
                pos_hint={'bottom': 1, 'left': 1},)
    flo.add_widget(label)
    
    # Build the text
    text = Label(text='The beetle looks at the sky',
                color=(0,0,0,1),
                font_size=20,
                size_hint=(0.25, 0.25),
                pos_hint={'top': 1, 'right': 1},)
    flo.add_widget(text)
    bkr.add_widget(flo)

    """PAGE 3
    """
    # Create the pages base widget
    flo = FloatLayout()

    # Build the image
    image = AsyncImage(source='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQac3tmjWwO-o62Cm3iUAby6EVLWNG226UOJQ&usqp=CAU',
                allow_stretch = True,
                keep_ratio = True,
                size_hint = (0.5, 0.5),
                pos_hint = {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.25},)
    flo.add_widget(image)

    # Build the label
    label = Label(text='Butterfly',
                color=(0,0,0,1),
                font_size=60,
                size_hint=(0.25, 0.25),
                pos_hint={'bottom': 1, 'left': 1},)
    flo.add_widget(label)
    
    # Build the text
    text = Label(text='The butterfly flaps its wings',
                color=(0,0,0,1),
                font_size=20,
                size_hint=(0.25, 0.25),
                pos_hint={'top': 1, 'right': 1},)
    flo.add_widget(text)
    bkr.add_widget(flo)

    # Return the root widget
    return bkr

# Create the App class 
class BookletApp(App): 
    def build(self): 
        return render_kivy_carousel()

# Run the App 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    BookletApp().run()
```

Can someone please let me know the correct way to do this. What I want is for text to stay within its float on its slide, and to do this by wrapping and/or resizing/scaling with the window/slide.

Thanks

Comment: There is no `left` or `bottom` keys for `size_hint`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint).

Comment: Oops, I meant `pos_hint`.

Comment: Use a kv rule for your label classes, with `text_size: self.size`

Comment: @inclement I could but given I call the render_kivy_carousel() function I am not sure how to structure the kv file. Can you post a sample kv file that solves the problem above with my code?

Comment: @John Anderson yes it does, see the float documentation https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html

Comment: There is no `left` or `bottom` keys for `pos_hint`. Read the link that you posted and follow the `pos_hint` link there (which takes you to my posted link). The valid keys are ‘x’, ‘right’, ‘center_x’, ‘y’, ‘top’, ‘center_y’, and `pos`. There is no `left` or `bottom`. For `left` you should use `x`, and for `bottom` you should use `y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concocted two widgets that inherit from standard Kivy widgets and have the desired behaviour. This may not be the best way to do it but it works.

**Text Wrapping Widget**
This widget acts like a "text box" and the text inside it wraps. You can replace `Button` with `Label` but buttons have more functionality. All the attributes and methods of `Button` are available.

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
...
class WrapBox(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(
            width=lambda *x:
                self.setter('text_size')(self, (self.width, None)),
            texture_size=lambda *x: 
                self.setter('height')(self, self.texture_size[1]))
...
txtbox = WrapBox(text='wrap me up in your love baby')
txtbox.color = (0,0,0,1)
txtbox.font_size = 60
```

**Text Resizing Widget**
This widget acts like a "text box" and the text inside it resizes as the window it is in resizes. As you can see the underlying widget is actually an `Image` drawn from the texture in a `Button`. All the attributes and methods of `Button` are available.

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
...
class ResizeBox(Image):
    text = StringProperty('')
    def on_text(self, *args):
        # Just get large texture:
        lbl = Button(text=self.text)
        # Value that'll give texture bigger than screen size
        # Small values result in blur.
        lbl.font_size = '1000dp'  
        lbl.texture_update()
        # Set it to image, it'll be scaled to image size automatically
        self.texture = lbl.texture
...
txtbox = ResizeBox(text='resize me with your love baby')
txtbox.color = (0,0,0,1)
txtbox.font_size = 60
```

[image: Wrapped and Resized]